# Fetch SINGLE entry and display it using MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to check if an entry exists, and I managed to do so but my if condition (if entry exits)
I want to display the whole record in the database.

```
$checkstudentID = mysqli_query
($dbcon, "SELECT studentid from courses WHERE studentid = '$studentid'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($checkstudentID) > 0){
     $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $checkstudentID);
     $row   = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

      $studentid = $row['studentid'];
      $cc    = $row['ckb '];
    }
```

- **First Question is : is it `SELECT studentid from courses` or

  SELECT studentid second input from courses
- I'm getting the following errors :

  *- **mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string*** on line 32
- ***mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given*** on line 33

**line 32** : $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $checkstudentID);

**line 33**: $row   = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

I'm aware PDO is much better nowadays but I'm not "well informed" on how to use it and still learning mysqli and mysql methods

Comment: Running `mysqli_query` twice? What for?

Comment: Please start by reading PHP manual

Comment: you mean in the $result = mysqli_query ? I need it for the fetch function or can I do something like
mysqli_num_rows($dbcon, $checkstudentID > 0) 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($mysqli_num_rows) ... 
I'm guessing its completely wrong ?

Comment: Please start by reading PHP manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select `ckb`, and prepare the query:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbcon, "SELECT ckb from courses WHERE studentid = ?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $studentid); //use i if its an int

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $ckb);

    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    printf("studentId = %s | ckb =  %s\n", $ckb, $studentid);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($dbcon);
```

Comment: It works, however this showed up
Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Comment: you have only one place holder `?` so Use only one bind `s` for string or `i` for int, just 1 not more, not less

Comment: taking the order into consideration ofcourse ? 
so having 3 place holders would be "i","s","s", as the first one is an integer (studentid) ..thank you for your help ^^

Comment: sorry its "i,s,s" * ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61603/discussion-between-azizi-and-meda).

Answer (score -1):

Correct code:

```
$checkstudentID = mysqli_query
($dbcon, "SELECT studentid, ckb from courses WHERE studentid = '$studentid'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($checkstudentID) > 0){
     $row   = mysqli_fetch_row($checkstudentID);

      $studentid = $row['studentid'];
      $cc         = $row['ckb '];
    }
```